# Checking if command line arguments are empty/null

Tags: java, arguments

If i am providing two arguments over the command line args[0] and args[1]. How do individually check if either of the arguments are empty/null?

Comment: They wouldn't be present if they were empty / null.

Comment: But if i need to set them to a variable how do i check if they are null/empty?

Comment: check the length of the Strings args array

Comment: So args[1].length() == 0? That still does not seem to be working. The only one i need to check if whether null is args[1], i don't care about arg[0].

Comment: so i should check if(args.length < 1)? This still does not seem to be working.

Comment: Define "not working".

Comment: @sam `so i should check if(args.length < 1)?`  yes something like this (based upon your logic).

Comment: The argument strings will not be null.  The `args` array will not be `null`.  (Exception ... if you call `main` from your own code with bogus args ...)  Of course, args.length could be zero, or any of the args could be an empty string.  But no `null` values are possible if `main` is invoked normally on JVM startup.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a simple example Sam:

```
if (args.length > 0) {
    if (!args[0].isEmpty()) { 
        // Do whatever with arg[0] (the first argument)
    }
    if (!args[1].isEmpty()) { 
        // Do whatever with arg[1] (the second argument)
    }
}
```

Comment: how would args[0] be empty?

Comment: Then what about `args[2]`? Don't you think it would be helpful if you have used `for` loop instead of `if`?

Comment: (@ScaryWombat - It is possible.  `java MainClass ""` will do it.)

Comment: Oh boy....where in the question does it mention args[2]?